# Embed code for my web page

Tags: asp.net

I've created a web application in asp.net. I've to generate embed code for one of my page so that other websites can embed that code in their websites. Tell me what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Question is entirely too vague.  What do you mean by "embed code?"  No idea what you are after here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try IFRAME or a javascript depending on what you want to do. An example is right here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair).

Answer (score 0):

You can provide code for an iframe that contains your page, which usually isn't so great. Or you can provide a little snippet of javascript that will then write your content into the page, which in most cases is better. If you really don't want anyone to mess with the code, use the iframe though since javascript can't really access your code inside of an iframe to make changes.